# Injection of arbitrary object into Spring bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

My class contains several methods those return some Java objects, i.e. InputStream and OutputStream:

```
public class Provider {
    public InputStream getInputStream() { ... }
    public OutputStream getOutputStream() { ... }
}
```

From the other hand I have a third-party class whose constructor can accept InputStream and OutputStream:

```
public class Consumer {
    public Consumer(InputStream is, OutputStream os) { ... }
}
```

The issue is: how to inject dependency on Provider's streams into Consumer bean?

Here is my XML file for Spring:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">
     <bean id="provider" class="org.example.Provider" />
     <bean id="consumer" class="org.example.Consumer">
         <constructor-arg value="#{provider.inputStream}" />
         <constructor-arg value="#{provider.outputStream}" />
     </bean>
 </beans>
```

Unforunatelly, the solution above leads to the following error:

```
Apr 01, 2014 10:54:59 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@5f18cd5: display name [org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@5f18cd5]; startup
date [Tue Apr 01 10:54:59 MSK 2014]; root of context hierarchy
Apr 01, 2014 10:54:59 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from file [C:\Test\context.xml]
Apr 01, 2014 10:54:59 AM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext obtainFreshBeanFactory
INFO: Bean factory for application context [org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext@5f18cd5]: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2d30be8c
Apr 01, 2014 10:54:59 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2d30be8c: defining beans [provider,consumer]; root of factory hierarchy
Apr 01, 2014 10:54:59 AM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry destroySingletons
INFO: Destroying singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@2d30be8c: defining beans [provider,consumer]; root of factory hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'consumer' defined in file [C:\Test\context.xml]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.io.InputStream]: Could not convert constructor argument value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.io.InputStream]: Failed to convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.io.InputStream]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not retrieve InputStream for file [C:\Test\#{provider.getInputStream()}]: #{provider.getInputStream()} (File specified cannot be found)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:565)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:193)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:925)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:835)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:440)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
        at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:140)
        at org.springframework.context.support.FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.<init>(FileSystemXmlApplicationContext.java:84)
        at org.example.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:9)
```

This error log looks very weird and I'm really confused what's going on...

**UPD:** Full stacktrace have been appended to the post.

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace.

Comment: Which version of Spring Framework are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your config will cause Spring to want to call:

```
 new com.example.Consumer("#{provider.inputStream}","#{provider.outputStream}");
```

... that is, `Consumer(String,String)`. But that constructor doesn't exist, so it fails.

Your error message `Could not convert constructor argument value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [java.io.InputStream]` says that. *"The constructor takes `InputStream` but you gave me `String`"*.

You need to ask Spring to create your Provider, then call that object's methods to               create the InputStream and OutputStream has Spring beans. Then use those in your Consumer:

```
<bean id="provider"
     class="com.example.Provider" />

<bean id="inputStream"
   factory-bean="provider"
   factory-method="getInputStream"/>

<bean id="outputStream"
   factory-bean="provider"
   factory-method="getOutputStream"/>

<bean id="consumer" class="com.example.Consumer">
     <constructor-arg ref="inputStream" />
     <constructor-arg ref="outputStream" />
</bean>
```

You can also do this inline, e.g.

```
<bean id="consumer" class="com.example.Consumer">
     <constructor-arg>
         <bean factory-bean="provider" factory-method="getInputStream"/>
     </constructor-arg>
     <constructor-arg>
         <bean factory-bean="provider" factory-method="getOutputStream"/>
     </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

---

Based on the [Spring Expression Language docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/expressions.html#expressions-beandef) (I haven't tested), the following may also work:

```
 <bean id="consumer" class="com.example.Consumer">
     <constructor-arg value="#{provider.getInputStream()}" />
     <constructor-arg value="#{provider.getOutputStream()}" />
 </bean>
```

... possibly helping it along with:

```
<constructor-arg type="java.io.InputStream" value="#{provider.getInputStream()}" />
```

Comment: Ok, this will work. But is there a way to use SpEL expression in constructor-arg at all? How can I say Spring that that string is a parsable SpEL?

Comment: must admit SpEL is new to me, but I looked at the docs. Does `value="#{provider.getInputStream()}"` work?

Comment: I have just tried `value="#{provider.getInputStream()}"`. No effect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of providing the consumer with two streams, you could instead inject the actual provider bean.

The consumer class should then look like this:

```
public class Consumer {
    public Consumer(Provider provider) { ... }
}
```

and the config xml should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">
     <bean id="provider" class="org.example.Provider" />
     <bean id="consumer" class="com.example.Consumer">
         <constructor-arg ref="provider" />
     </bean>
 </beans>
```

Comment: That would worth if there were a constructor `Consumer(Provider)`. But there isn't one.

Comment: Well, author of Consumer is not me and I'm not able to modify it. Of course I can use wrapper with appropriate constructor, but it's not a Spring way, I believe

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks everyone! Summary, there were two possible ways to overcome that challenge:

1. Use `Provider` as a bean factory;  or
2. Upgrade Spring version. Spring 4.0.2 manages with SPeLs pretty fine!